# performing N independent 1D FFT on a 2D matrix with FFTW

Tags: fftw

I have a 2 dimensional matrix with each column corresponding to one independent signal. I am going to perform N 1D fft on each column. In matlab, apply a fft to a 2D matrix will do the trick. But I am porting my code to c++ with fftw. I wonder if there is a way to do so. I try the following code by setting the column size to 1 and row size to 4 (total row number), but it does not help.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include "fftw3.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  complex<double> data[4][2];
  data[0][0] = complex<double>(1,1);
  data[1][0] = complex<double>(2,1);
  data[2][0] = complex<double>(3,1);
  data[3][0] = complex<double>(4,1);

  data[0][1] = complex<double>(1,1);
  data[1][1] = complex<double>(1,2);
  data[2][1] = complex<double>(1,3);
  data[3][1] = complex<double>(1,4);

  cout << "original data ..." << endl;
  cout << data[0][0] << '\t' << data[0][1] << endl;
  cout << data[1][0] << '\t' << data[1][1] << endl;
  cout << data[2][0] << '\t' << data[2][1] << endl;
  cout << data[3][0] << '\t' << data[3][1] << endl;
  cout << endl << endl;

  fftw_plan plan=fftw_plan_dft_2d(4, 1,(fftw_complex*)&data[0][0], (fftw_complex*)&data[0][0], FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);
  fftw_execute(plan);
  cout << "after fftw ..." << endl;
  cout << data[0][0] << '\t' << data[0][1] << endl;
  cout << data[1][0] << '\t' << data[1][1] << endl;
  cout << data[2][0] << '\t' << data[2][1] << endl;
  cout << data[3][0] << '\t' << data[3][1] << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Above code takes the first and second row and reshape them to 2x2 matrix then perform a 2D fft.

Up to now, the only way that comes to my mind is as follow. Let's say I have NxM (N rows, M columns), I create M fftw plans for M 1D fftw. I execute M fftw in serial to get the result. But in practical application, the matrix is very big, M is so large. It is very inefficient to do this way. Any better idea? Thanks.

Comment: Could you try to add the flag `FFTW_IN_PLACE` ? It must be used since the input array is also the output array. http://www.fftw.org/fftw2_doc/fftw_3.html Moreover, 2D fft is different from the 1D fft. You can use use a for loop on the rows, and call `fftw_execute()` see http://www.fftw.org/doc/New_002darray-Execute-Functions.html#New_002darray-Execute-Functions. The best option would be to use [`fftw_plan fftw_plan_many_dft()`](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs)

Answer (score 2):

For those stumbling across this nowadays, the FFTW devs have implemented routines for this operation, which is faster than looping through each column and taking a separate transform. You certainly don't want to take a 2D transform (as is shown in the question), which is mathematically different than row-wise 1D transforms.

The key to you question is in `fftw_plan_many_dft`. [Here is a link to the full documentation.](http://www.fftw.org/doc/Advanced-Complex-DFTs.html#Advanced-Complex-DFTs)

Here is an example (modifed from the above link) that illustrates what you're looking for.

```
#include "fftw3.h"

int main() {

    fftw_complex *A; // array of data
    A = (fftw_complex*) fftw_malloc(sizeof(fftw_complex)*10*3);
    
    // ...
    
    /* Transform each column of a 2d array with 10 rows and 3 columns */
    int rank = 1; /* not 2: we are computing 1d transforms */
    int n[] = {10}; /* 1d transforms of length 10 */
    int howmany = 3;
    int idist = 1;
    int odist = 1;
    /* distance between two elements in the same column */
    int istride = 3;
    int ostride = 3;
    
    int *inembed = n, *onembed = n;
    
    /* forward, in-place, 1D transform of each column */
    fftw_plan p;
    p = fftw_plan_many_dft(rank, n, howmany, A, inembed, istride, idist, A, onembed, ostride, odist, FFTW_FORWARD, FFTW_ESTIMATE);

    
    // ...
    
    /* run transform */
    fftw_execute_dft(p, A, A);
    
    
    // ...
    
    /* we don't want memory leaks */
    fftw_destroy_plan(p);
    fftw_free(A);

}
```